# Aptana 3 Studio: Can I put the www Apache folder as workspace?

Tags: php, eclipse, ide, aptana, aptana3

I am very new in PHP world and now I have install Apatana 3 Studio and I have some question to you about PHP configuration in this development environment.

Seems that my configuration work well but I don't know if it is configured in a smart way...

I use Ubuntu and I have installed Apache 2 web server

Executing a simple php file (that is inside my /var/www folder) conteining phpinfo() function:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

I obtain some information and seems that I have installed Apache 2 web server under this path: /etc/php5/apache2 and that the php.ini file have this path: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Infact, this is part of the phpinfo() output that I obtain:

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php5/apache2 Loaded
>
> Configuration File   /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Ok, so I have configured my PHP environment settings in the following way:

1) I have create a new WorkSpace so that it matches the folder /var/www

2) I have set an external web server in this way: Windows ---> Preferences ---> Web Servers ---> New ---> External Web Server and I have put the following value:

Name: Apache

Base URL: [code]http://localhost[/code]

Document Root: /etc/php5/apache2

Doing so I can create a new project inside /var/www and if I execute some PHP file of this project by: Runs as ---> Php Server this file is executed in a browser windows.

Is it a right configuration? my douts depend by the fact that I have also try to create a new workspace inside the /var/www directory, for example: /var/www/AptanaWS but if I create a new project in this workspace if I try do execute a project file I have an error because it try to open the following URL:

[code]http://localhost/Test/test.php[/code]

and not the right URL that is:

[code]http://localhost/AptanaWS/Test/test.php[/code]

So, can I put my **/var/www** as my Work Space or is it a bad thing?

Comment: I've alywas been using www and not a problem so far; you need to give proper permissions, as Aptana needs both read and write privileges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it. Actually, I've did this with my Aptana install on Windows. On ubuntu I'm not using Aptana but it's the same principle..

Answer (score 0):

As long as you create new projects as a **sub-folder** of /var/www you are fine.

Creating sub-folders is to allow for multiple projects to be previewed with the same server.

If you wish, you can place your project directly in the root of the web server, but note that if you delete the project, and select to "delete files on disk" it will **delete the entire directory and all contents**.

Reference: [Setting up an external web server to preview PHP and other non-HTML pages](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Setting+up+an+external+web+server+to+preview+PHP+and+other+non-HTML+pages)